# Apply jQuery styles after dynamically loading the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery $.get to get some html content.

```
 $.get(url, function( data ) {
        // process the content as a cell and append to a table.
    }
```

The html content has a date picker.

```
<input name="dropdate" id="dropdate"  value="" class="datepicker_ddmmmyy"/>
```

`‘datepicker_ddmmmyy’` is a css class and defined in the main page to format the date. The problem here is after completing the request, datepicker_ddmmmyy style is not get applied to the input element and when I click on the text box calendar is not popping up. Using F12, I could see that style class is present with the element, but not get applied. 
 I tried `$(#elementid).trigger(“create”), $(#elementid).trigger(“enhance”).` Both did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you're initializing these jQuery plugins when the document is ready, and the items, when added via your `$.get()` method do not exist to have the methods and functionality bound to them.

I would recommend either explicitly adding those initialization methods to the `success` handler of your `$.get()` method, or invoking a function which is aware of how many initializers it should care about (if you have a few).

Comment: Thank you @James Lai, It worked. I initialized styles within the success handler.